# order array of objects based on array of IDs

Tags: ecmascript-6

if I have an array of

```
const users = [
  { id: 2, name: 'User 2' },
  { id: 5, name: 'User 5' },
  { id: 3, name: 'User 3' },
]
```

how can I order them based on this array

```
const ids = [5, 2, 3]
```

so that the result would be something like

```
const users = [
  { id: 5, name: 'User 5' },
  { id: 2, name: 'User 2' },
  { id: 3, name: 'User 3' },
]
```

I tried `ids.map(id => users.find(u => u.id === id))` but I think that is not optimised because we keep doing `find()` to same collection for every `id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `Map` object that contains the sort index for each value.  Then, use that sort index to actually sort the array:

```
const ids = [5,2,3];

// Create sorting index using a Map object
// The id value is the key, the the index in that array is the value 
//   in the map and is used as the sort index
const mapIndex = new Map();
for (let [i, id] of ids.entries()) {
   mapIndex.set(id, i);
}

const users = [
  { id: 2, name: 'User 2' },
  { id: 5, name: 'User 5' },
  { id: 3, name: 'User 3' },
];

// sort using the mapIndex
users.sort((a, b) => {
    return mapIndex.get(a.id) - mapIndex.get(b.id);
});
```

This assumes there are no `.id` values that are not in your ids array.  If that is a possibility, then you need to define what the sort position is for id values not in your `ids` array and add protection for that in your sort callback.